# windows 8.1 won't let me boot using Ubuntu

Tags: boot, uefi, grub-efi

I have a Lenovo laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 8. I have tried both desktop versions of Ubuntu, and I get the same result. Upon restarting mt laptop I get a start screen called 'windows boot menu' that allows a choice to boot with Windows or Ubuntu, after choosing Ubuntu I get an error. It tells me Windows failed to boot.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Were there some instructions online that you followed? For example, did you alter any BIOS settings regarding UEFI / Legacy boot?

Comment: Have you tried using refit/refind? these work much better than grub for uefi in my experience.

Comment: ... I'm new to all of this, so consider me to know not how to do anything. and yes, I'v tried to use other answers, but they seem to be outdated, or had different problems.

Comment: What other answers? You need to be specific about the actual details of what you have done and what you have tried, otherwise it's very difficult to give you advice.

Comment: I installed the liveCD, it prompted me to reboot, then it refused to run Ubuntu, the reason it gave was simply that windows couldn't boot, yet i didn't try to boot windows

Comment: please open a terminal on the livecd and run `gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg` if the file is empty please do  `which grub && which refit && which refind`

Comment: I recommend you boot an Ubuntu live system (boot the installer, but choose the option to try Ubuntu rather than installing it) and then run the [Boot Info Script.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) (It's in the package called `boot-info-script`, IIRC.) It will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your file here.